# java encryption cannnot encrypt any string?

Tags: java, testing, encryption

I have made an encryption and decryption class and now i want to test it.
The encrypter shold take som text and encrypt it into an .txt file. But it does not work.

```
public class Encryption extends FilterWriter{
private static int INKREMENT = 3;

protected Encryption(Writer arg0) {
    super(arg0);
}

public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException{
    String result = str.substring(0,off);
    for(int i = off; i<len+off; i++){
        result += (char) ((int) str.charAt(i)+ INKREMENT);
    }
    result += str.substring(off+len);
    out.write(result);
}
public void write(int c) throws IOException{
        out.write(c + INKREMENT);


}
public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException{
    for(int i = off; i < len + off; i++){
        cbuf[i] = (char)((int) cbuf[i] + INKREMENT);
    }
    out.write(cbuf,off,len);
}
```

}

My test ? I dont know what to write to get a string encrypted and saved in the text.txt file

```
Writer out = new Encryption(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text.txt")));
```

Comment: Just say it - you copied random encryption code from internet and unable to use it.

Comment: Encryption?  Yeah if it was still 1512.

Comment: this is link... [How to encrypt String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205135/how-to-encrypt-string-in-java) and also [How to programatically encrypt/decrypt plain text credentials in JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308609/how-to-programatically-encrypt-decrypt-plain-text-credentials-in-jsp) happy coding :-)

Comment: 'INKREMENT' makes it super-secure.

Comment: You have problem with encryption or with writing to file?

Comment: No i have tried to use all the ways that i know to write to an txt file but it doens not work

Comment: "It does not work" contains 1 bit of information. Not a useful statement. What happens instead?

Comment: never mind. i figured it out..

Answer (score 0):

See `javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream`. It's already done.